# oracle 11g not able to connect with scott user, showing: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle

whenever I'm trying to connect with scott it is showing invalid username/password,
tried this:
`alter user scott account unlock;`

> SP2-0640: Not connected

```
alter user scott identified by tiger;
```

> SP2-0640: Not connected

[image]

Comment: have you tried to reconnect with a dba account and then re-issue the commands? The error just indicates you are not connected (e.g.with system account).

Comment: what do you get when you're connected to `system`, and issue `select count(1) from dba_users where username = 'SCOTT';`?

Comment: yes i did, SQL> conn system as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> ALTER USER scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger ACCOUNT UNLOCK
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'SCOTT' does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Installing path of the Oracle 11g In default it is present `C:` Drive, then move to `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin`

here you can find a file named scott.sql

Open the SQL Command Line and login as  `conn system/ (password set during the installation of oracle 11g)`

Run the Below script (Note: File name is appended at the end)

```
@ C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql
```

Now you can query the `SELECT * FROM all_users;` to see the scott schema created

Alternatively you can do this by using SQL developer by creating a connection to SYSTEM and run the above script

After the creation the default username : `SCOTT` password: `TIGER`

Answer (score 0):

**Connect with a DBA Account and Issue an Alter User Command**

The error you are seeing indicates you are no longer connected to the database. You were logged in as system@db, but when you tried to connect as scott@db, you no longer have a database connection.

Here I replicate your experience:

```
SYSTEM@db>conn system@db as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

SYS@db>conn scott@db
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

@>alter user account scott unlock;
SP2-0640: Not connected
@>alter user scott identified by tiger;
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

Here I reconnect and then issue an `alter user` command to unlock the user account and set a new password.

```
 @>conn system@db as sysdba
    Enter password:

    Connected.

    SYS@db>ALTER USER scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

    User altered.

    SYS@db>conn scott/tiger@db
    Connected.
```

---

Addendum

My steps provided assumed you had the scott schema installed. If the scott schema does not exist, it would be good to see if the default 11g database sample schemas exist.

The schema account scott is no longer a default schema in the 11g database.  The 11g documentation states:

> "Oracle used the schema SCOTT with its two prominent tables EMP and
>   DEPT for many years. With advances in Oracle Database technology,
>   these tables have become inadequate to show even the most basic
>   features of Oracle Database and other Oracle products. "

I would recommend reviewing to see if the other default sample schemas are installed.  The hr account is most similar to the scott schema.

Here is a list of common sample schema usernames:

```
username IN (
    'HR',
    'OE',
    'PM',
    'SH',
    'IX'
)
```

Check to see if the person whom performed the installation used the database configuration assistant and opted to install the sample schemas.

If the schemas were not created at the time of installation, the document, "Oracle® Database Sample Schemas 11g Release 1 (11.1) B28328-03", describes the steps to do this in chapter 2, Installation.

Comment: SQL> conn system as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> ALTER USER scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger ACCOUNT UNLOCK
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'SCOTT' does not exist . still i'm getting the error message user 'SCOTT' dos not exist

Answer (score 0):

In the comment part i especially asked for querying

`select count(1) from dba_users where username = 'SCOTT';`. I'd like to learn if user exists.

For the message you get `ORA-01017`,

- the First possible reason is what message tells us(*invalid
  username/password*).
- Secondly, you may not have an account named `SCOTT`. i.e. the above
  query gives `0`(zero).

In this case :

you should create mentioned user ( when you're connected to `system` ):

```
SQL> conn system/pwd
Connected.
SQL> create user scott identified by tiger;
```

and grant related privileges :

```
SQL> grant connect to scott;
SQL> grant resource to scott;
```

and then you can connect by issuing :

```
SQL> conn scott/tiger
Connected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Oracle sql developer.
In the sql developer paste the path of scott.sql file(C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql) with '@' infront of it.

```
@ C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql
```

Run script
Script Output -> *Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected*
Connect using SQL Command Line

```
conn scott/TIGER;
```